# Can I override which URL openconnect POSTs to?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openconnect

A while ago, a connection to a VPN broke. The admin says it's because `openconnect` is sending a `POST` to the wrong URL. The dump looks something like this:

```
echo 'MyPassword' | openconnect -b --pid-file=/tmp/openconnect-pid --user="MyUser" --printcookie --dump-http-traffic entry.foo.corp/subGroup
POST https://entry.foo.corp/subGroup
Attempting to connect to server 195.222.249.123:443
Connected to 195.222.249.123:443
SSL negotiation with entry.foo.corp
Connected to HTTPS on entry.foo.corp
> POST /subGroup HTTP/1.1
> Host: entry.foo.corp
> User-Agent: Open AnyConnect VPN Agent v8.05-1
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: identity
> X-Transcend-Version: 1
> X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
> X-AnyConnect-Platform: linux-64
> X-Support-HTTP-Auth: true
> X-Pad: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 219
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config-auth client="vpn" type="init"><version who="vpn">v8.05-1</version><device-id>linux-64</device-id><group-access>https://entry.foo.corp/subGroup</group-access></config-auth>
```

```
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2023 08:56:31 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config-auth client="vpn" type="auth-request" aggregate-auth-version="2">
<opaque is-for="sg">
<tunnel-group>AnyConnect-subGroup-TunnelGroup</tunnel-group>
<config-hash>1679989103949</config-hash>
</opaque>
<auth id="main">
<title>Login</title>
<message>Please enter your username and password.</message>
<banner></banner>
<form>
<input type="text" name="username" label="Username:"></input>
<input type="password" name="password" label="Password:"></input>
</form>
</auth>
</config-auth>
```

```
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
Password:
POST https://entry.foo.corp/
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: entry.foo.corp
> User-Agent: Open AnyConnect VPN Agent v8.05-1
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: identity
> X-Transcend-Version: 1
> X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
> X-AnyConnect-Platform: linux-64
> X-Support-HTTP-Auth: true
> X-Pad: 00000000000
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 373
>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config-auth client="vpn" type="auth-reply"><version who="vpn">v8.05-1</version><device-id>linux-64</device-id><opaque is-for="sg">
<tunnel-group>AnyConnect-subGroup-TunnelGroup</tunnel-group>
<config-hash>1679989103949</config-hash>
</opaque><auth><username>MyUser</username><password>MyPassword</password></auth></config-auth>
```

```
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Close
Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2023 08:56:31 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
HTTP body http 1.0 (-1)
SSL socket closed uncleanly
Unexpected 404 result from server
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

So, in the first request, the `POST` goes to `https://entry.foo.corp/subGroup`.

But in the second request, it instead goes to `https://entry.foo.corp`. That looks wrong, and the admin of that VPN agrees that it's the wrong URL.

So, is there a way I can tell `openconnect` that it should `POST` to the same URL both times?

(Better yet: is there a better explanation on why this is suddenly failing?)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This is Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS and OpenConnect version v8.20-1. (It previously occurred on an older release, so I tried upgrading, to no avail.)

Comment: Upgrading never fixes an ongoing issue it just carries it over.

Answer (score 1):

The second POST request is not sent to the correct URL, one solution is to create a local reverse proxy that intercepts the request and forwards it to the correct URL.

First lets install `socat` `sudo apt-get install socat` then we start the reverse proxy to listen on port 8080 and forwards all traffic to `entry.foo.corp:443` `socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr TCP:entry.foo.corp:443`.

Then modify your `Openconnect` to use this reverse proxy `echo 'MyPassword' | openconnect -b --pid-file=/tmp/openconnect-pid --user="MyUser" --printcookie --dump-http-traffic http://localhost:8080/subGroup`

If it still dont work try to update `Openconnect`.

Comment: Thanks!

This got me a few steps closer, but would have `openconnect` pass the wrong `Host:` header. So I did the same thing with Caddy instead, where I can use `header_up Host entry.foo.corp` to override that. That gives me `<auth id="success">` and `Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, but then `No MTU received. Aborting`. Odd.